# Subtract single value from numpy column preserving original data shape

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I want to subtract a given value from a numpy column. For example given a 2-D matrix I want to subtract an arbitrary value from a given column.

I know that this could be achieved with the following code:

```
numpy_matrix[:, 0] -= my_value
```

Where basically I am subtracting `my_value` from the 0 column.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
result = numpy_matrix[:,0] - my_value
```

where `result` has the original shape of `numpy_matrix`, instead of being a single vector. For example, if `numpy_matrix.shape=(4,3)`, with the code above I will get `result.shape=(4,)`.

What I want to do is to subtract my value from the selected column, and return a matrix which has the same identical shape of the original one (`numpy_matrix`) but with the "transformed" column.

Is there a way to do this efficiently in numpy without subtracting and then concatenating the remaining columns "manually" from the original `numpy_matrix`?

**Edit**: Since i noticed that it was kind of unclear, my goal is to create a new matrix identical to the original one (same shape, same data) but with the i-th column modified by the subtraction operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood, what you're trying exactly, but I think this does what you want:

```
import numpy as np

def sub(mtx, col, num):
    # ret = np.ones(mtx.shape, np.float16)
    # ret[:,:] = mtx[:,:]
    ret = mtx.copy()
    ret[:,col] -= num
    return ret

original = np.ones((4,6), np.float16) # change to your shape and type
# fill with your original values here
result = sub(original, 3, 3)

print("Original:")
print(original)
print("Result:")
print(result)
```

I would create a new matrix with the same shape, fill it with the original elements and then overwrite the desired column.

```
Original:
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
Result:
[[ 1.  1.  1. -2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. -2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. -2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. -2.  1.  1.]]
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I needed, even though I thought it was possible to achieve this by means of some numpy method without copying "manually" the two matrices (since probably they're internally optimized), but it still does the job

Comment: Well, you can copy them with simply the `copy()` function too. So you use a built-in function, not copying manually. But there might be a faster/better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer you better if I know you want to overwrite the original array or create a new one with the same size but the first column is subtracted by a scalar.

Overwrite on the original array, we can do as you provide the first code block(good and short), or another way around (same logic):

```
numpy_matrix[:,0]=numpy_matrix[:,0]-my_value
```

or

```
numpy_matrix[:,0]=result
```

If you want to create a new one (sounds strange to me), but copy the original array and write the same logic to overwrite on the new array.